# Asp.net MVC Ajax - Disabling button in ajax.beginform?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-ajax

I'm using microsoft ajax and `ajax.beginform`.

It's working great for model binding my partial view, but I need to conditionally disable some of the buttons in my form itself depending on what comes back from the server.

How can I go about this without using JQuery?

Comment: Thus far, I've ended up having my partial view update itself.  Seems to work, I'll make a more efficient rewrite later.  For now, having total control over the form is most important.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought instead about using two separate views instead, and have your conditional logic in your controller determine which view to display.

Comment: I didn't want to have to do a full postback to get the form that contained conditionally enabled controls.  Maybe I should've clarified that it had to be a solution without a postback.